# Cosa significa "sbaragliato" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> A norma di Universo le grandi stragi non son neppure un brivido, sebbene l'Universo della umana memoria protesti. E s'erano affidati alla carta, al legno, alle pietre, queste materie più salde di un corpo umano, perché l'umanità civile continuasse. Ma ecco scritture, intagli, colori violentemente **sbaragliati** e incineriti, mentre l'ingegnoso che li concepì è ridotto un meschino senza volto, scacciato dal sasso dove univa i piedi tremando, all'orlo di una voragine.

Ho letto la [definizione di "sbaragliare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sbaragliare/). Tuttavia, non riesco a capire cosa significa che i colori sono "violentemente sbaragliati". Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sbaragliati* e *incineriti* si riferiscono a "scritture, intagli e colori", non solo a "colori".

"Sbaragliare" si usa quando si parla di guerre, battaglie, contese. Qui immagino che Anna Banti voglia dire che se è vero che le "grandi stragi", in confronto all'immensità dell'universo, sono piccole, insignificanti, gli uomini, raccontandole o dipingendole o raffigurandole in bassorilievi, hanno voluto conservarne la memoria. Però, anche le parole, anche i colori, anche gli intagli nel marmo si perdono, sbiadiscono.

Invece di dire "si perdono", "sbiadiscono" (o altre parole migliori di queste...), l'autrice ha cercato delle parole nel campo semantico delle "stragi", perché è a queste che si riferisce.